# Wheels keep getting buckled

Tags: wheels

I have a touring bike with one side-bag on the back frame.
On average I cycle 60 miles a week.
How often do I need to buy new wheels?
As of late I keep buckling both wheels.
Can anyone please help with my question.
Thanks!!

Comment: Wow! Are you hitting pot holes? Are you riding a road bike on dirt/gravel trails for your commute? What do you mean by "buckle"? Who is assembling your wheels? I've put thousands of road miles on a wheel set and not had any issues beyond occasional truing.

Comment: You have a problem.  Either the wheels you're getting are very poorly assembled, or you are somehow subjecting them to extreme forces (perhaps due to a fault of some sort in the bike frame).  Simply having a pannier on only one side would not cause this.  (You need to describe a bit better what happens when they "buckle" -- eg, do spokes break?)

Comment: In all my riding (I'd guess 20K miles total) I've only had a wheel buckle once, when I had my rear wheel slide out from under me on a curve.

Comment: Yeah, something is pretty wrong here.

Comment: @Michael We will need more info to be able to help. Earlier comments have asked some useful questions. Also - how old is the bike, what price range or make is it, what weight is the bike carrying? Wheels commonly last the life of a bike in normal use. The typical end of a wheel is a crash or other abuse.

Comment: Hi Michael  - this question is old, and has no answers.  Would you like to post and accept your own new answer describing how it has gone for you in the past 11 months?   Did you buy some good wheels or press on with the old ones?